# How to import related products in normal import process?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, import

How to import related products in normal import process? How can I achieve this? Is there any method available for import related products?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, yes this can be done with Magento's Import / Export without the use of any extension.

Second, I would recommend taking one product, adding some related products to it in the Magento Admin, saving the product then exporting to CSV (System -> Import/Export -> Export).

You will notice two columns; `_links_related_sku` and `_links_related_position`

You will need to fill in those columns with the appropriate SKU. Please remember that each related product will need to be entered in a separate row (see screenshot).

This can be also done for crosssells and upsells.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The first sentence is wrong. It can not be done with Dataflow. It can be done with only import

Comment: @kab8609 Thanks it works but issue it is creating is if i have 2 products in csv for example sku A and another sku B. Now for SKU A I already have related product assign 
so in that column in csv I will not put any value for related but for upsell I will.

And for SKU B I add both values. So what it does is it removes related product from SKU A, as it dont have any value assigned in csv. 

I tried this from both Import/Export and Data flow profile.

Do you have any idea how to only update with currnt product assigned? Not replace it?