# How can I import related products into Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9

9.1.0 and when importing related products the file seems to run and then we get no information and the related products field has not imported.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Dataflow, follow this link: [How to import related products in normal import process?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7326/how-to-import-related-products-in-normal-import-process)

If you're doing it programmatically, you'll need to do this.

```
$data = array(
    product_id_1 => array(
        'position' => $position1
    ),
    product_id_2 => array(
        'position' => $position2
    ),
    // etc...
);
$product->setRelatedLinkData($data)
    ->save();
```