# Bulk edit of up-sell / cross-sell product items

Tags: catalog, up-sells, cross-sells

When I want to add a up-sell or cross-sell to an entire product-line, it becomes very tedious to edit one product at a tiem to modify those products.  It would be nice to select a group of products and perform an action like 'add cross-sell item'  or 'remove cross-sell item' in bulk.

Comment: This can be done using ImportExport: [How to import related products in normal import process?][1]


  [1]: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7326/how-to-import-related-products-in-normal-import-process

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [this free extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/ProductRelationsImport) can help.
It allows you to bulk import any kind of product relations (cross-sells, up-sells, related) via csv or manual input.
Full description on how to use can be [found here](https://github.com/tzyganu/ProductRelationsImport/blob/master/README.md).
In a few words, you need to generate a csv file or input manually the product ids or SKUs in the format described and select a method to relate the products.

- Relate all on one line to first product in line - first product in a line is the main product and all the others will be related to the main one
- Relate all products on one line - all products on one line will be related to each other
- Relate all products among themselves - all products in your csv or manual input will be related among themselves independent of the line they are on.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the original post I'm familiar with the export/import approach, I know it can be done that way, but that also seems tedious and error-prone, especially with the strange multi-row approach to 'sub objects'

Comment: @MarkE. I'm not talking about import/export. I just recommended an extension that I've built just for cases like this. When managing product relations becomes a drag. It's not a bullet proof solution, but it saves some time.

Answer (score 0):

For Manage cross sell,up sell,related and associated (grouped) product in bulk than you can do it with magento database without using any extension.
In magento all product relation store in `catalog_product_link` table so just modify that table for manage product relation.
Magento directly use sql query with read and wrire as below.

```
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
```

In `catalog_product_link` table `link_type_id` set from `catalog_product_link_type` table

```
link_type_id = '1' (Related Product)
link_type_id = '3' (Associate Product)
link_type_id = '4' (Up Sell Product)
link_type_id = '5' (Cross Sell Product)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Magmi Cross/Upsell Importer. It is part of the Magmi Plugin.
http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Cross/Upsell_Importer

This plugins handles 2 extra columns:

**us_skus** for upsell skus to link with current item

**cs_skus** for cross sell skus to link with current item

It's very easy to use and the import is much faster than Magento's inbuilt import/export.

Comment: Magmi is almost never a good idea. It bypasses Magento's model layer which enforces important business rules and ensures data consistency. Magmi has also suffered major security breaches in the past. Not recommended.

Comment: I'm using MAGMI for long time now and it was a solution for a lot of complicated situations to me, when it comes to importing and exporting, it's the best for Magento, I know there is a lot of contributions from developers and plugins, but I wish I can meet the founder and shake his hands and thank him a lot for the great effort he made.